# Install Windows 10 on iMac7,1

Tags: windows-10, bootable-media, imac

I got an old iMac7,1 with complete erased HDD. I wanted to install Windows 10 on it, but have problems.

When I created a bootable Windows 10 USB Stick (worked on an other laptop without a problem) and inserted it into the Mac, it is recognized as an EFI boot device. When I choose it to boot from, the screen with the boot devices freezes (mouse and keyboard also) and nothing happens.

Using etcher and Ubuntu I created a fully working boot media which is usable to install Ubuntu (tested). So the machine itself should work.
I tried:

- Windows 10 32 and 64 bit
- create boot stick with etcher, win32 disk imager, rufus, Windows media creation tool
- Windows 7 32 and 64 bit
- USB Stick with MBR and GPT, also NTFS and FAT32 (all combinations here)
- oscdimg.exe to create a 64 bit installation with 32 bit EFI
- removed bootmgr.exe from installation usb stick

I don´t have any more ideas on how to continue here, as the problem with freezing remains.

Comment: It's probably worth an hour reading https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406506/installing-windows-on-a-macbook-pro-15-inch-core-2-duo-without-mac-os-x [it might actually take that long just to read it ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin i followed the install instructions with ubuntu and now windows is installing, so I think it solved my problem. Thanks for your help!